# How to convert generated select tag to unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some dropdown boxes in javascript with select tag and now I want to convert it in unordered list. How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/4pwvg/

this is my code

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: you want to convert entire select into ul?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/07a9vz1h/

Comment: I want to style that dropdown boxes and for this I need to convert the select tag to ul

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("ol");
selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("li");
    option.innerHTML = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pwvg/261/)